# Excel rearrange data and sort

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

i have a table in excel with data in this format (with alot more data):

```
date source data1 data2
1.2.3   1   767     888
1.2.3   2   543     444
2.2.3   1   557     333 
2.2.3   3   576     777
```

It is a few thousand lines of data and 6 sources, a different number of dates with data for every source. I need to use some sort of excel magic to arrange the data like this:

```
date source data1 data2  source data1 data2  source . . .
1.2.3   1   767     888     2   543     444     3
2.2.3   1   557     333  
.
.
.
```

So that the sources come after eatchother horizontally and arranged by date. Any ideas on how i could rearrange and sort the data like that?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty small data sample and I have a hunch that it will not cover all the possible twists and turns in your data. If your source data is laid out like you describe, you can quickly create a table similar to your desired result with a pivot table.

To get started with pivot tables, take a look at [this intro tutorial](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Pivots/pivotstart.htm)